# Account to grant permissions for SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, reportserver

I am setting up a new instance of Report Server on a new box and need to create a couple new roles. The problem is that I don't have permissions to access /reports or /reportserver:

```
/reports: User '<username>' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

/reportserver: The permissions granted to user '<username>' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)
```

The domain user through which I am trying to access these has been granted full local admin rights. I would assume there might be a ReportServer user group in Local Users and Groups, but one doesn't exist.

The service account is the built-in account 'Network Service'. I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Any idea how I'd access the server to begin granting these permissions?

Comment: Have you tried "run as administrator" option for your browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign the permissions for the user on the report folder level? Doing this via report management URL (with Internet Explorer) by clicking the little arrow to the right of the report folder and selecting permissions.